# Is there a point to eating doughnuts?

Tags: brutal-doom

Around the maps in Brutal Doom, you'll occasionally find some doughnuts!

[image: Donuts!]

If you press <kbd>E</kbd> on them, they will disappear.  Presumably, after doing this, my character consumes them.  But is there any point? My health doesn't change at all from it so they don't seem to heal you.

What is the point of eating doughnuts?

Comment: It's probably an easter egg or cosmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's **very likely** to be just an Easter-Egg, I can't find any actual use for them.

The Easter Egg refers to *The Simpsons Doom* where donuts were used as health packs, I cannot guarantee you that it's definetly pointless to have it *(other than for the sake of completionism)*, but it's very likely that it's just that, an easter egg referring for another Mod of Doom: *The Simpsons Doom*

This [thread](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1058083) has a discussion of the (then) upcoming Doom mod, which is the first mention I could find of donuts.

Comment: I think that this is likely the best reason. I'm going to wait and see if any more answers come in, but yours will be rewarded once the bounty time is up.

Comment: I was on the Mods website, and found a dev video saying that in the upcoming V21 of the game, donuts and other food items will grant health upon eating them. Video: https://youtu.be/QYdKmVJS4NM?t=1m56s